# Ubuntu 14.04 on HP Chromebook 11

Tags: hp, chromebook

Hey guys I was wondering if I can install Ubuntu 14.04 on my new HP Chromebook 11. I like the Chrome OS but I would prefer to have Ubuntu on it. I was reading online and somebody said that it only works with Intel and not ARM.

Comment: I think it's possible with some tools like... `Crouton` ... I find some links with good explanation, So look at it. [Link-1](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/install-ubuntu-on-your-chromebook-using.html) and [Link-2](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-run-both-chrome-os-and-ubuntu-on-a-chromebook/)

Comment: i see, i gave my answer based on official releases, i never knew that there are other ways or workarounds, thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Desktop is not available for the ARM arch, but there is a Server version available, which is not suitable for you

Comment: Hey @younes , May be its a possible. See the comment on the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install Ubuntu *within* Chrome OS using [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton), and this does work on a HP Chromebook 11 as well. It will run as its own little chroot from a terminal command once installed.

There are full explanations [here](http://liliputing.com/2013/10/running-ubuntu-apps-hp-chromebook-11-video.html) & [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/install-ubuntu-on-your-chromebook-using.html) & [here](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-run-both-chrome-os-and-ubuntu-on-a-chromebook/), but the short version is:

1. Enter developer mode.
2. Open a browser tab and download the latest version of the Crouton
   script.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on your Chromebook to open a terminal window.
4. Type `shell` and hit enter.
5. Type `sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton` to see a list of options, or
6. Type `sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce` to just go ahead and
   install Ubuntu LTE with the xfce desktop environment. If you’d
   prefer to use GNOME, KDE, LXDE, Unity, or another desktop
   environment, use the appropriate name instead of xfce in the command
   above.
7. Create a username and password when you’re prompted.

Some applications may not play nice with the ARM chip, but the overall experience should be workable.